# Azure AD user unable to connect to Azure SQL Error: 18456,State:1,Class:14

Tags: sql-server, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

**BACKGROUND**

The user is defined in Azure AD and in Azure SQL.

- `test.user@company.com` is defined and active in Azure AD. I’m able to log in with this user in Azure portal.
- I have created a *contained database user* with the clause "from external provider" in the Azure SQL database and added the user to the `db_datareader` system role. The commands commits without error. I have compared the Asset ID in Azure AD and the SID in database and they match. I have tried with different users.
- I am able to login as an AD User assigned to the SQL servers assigned "Active Directory Admin"
- SQL Server users also login without any issue

**Login test in SSMS**

I have set default database to the specific database I’m trying to log into (Options-Connect to database).

I have tried with different Authentication modes:

- “Azure Active Directory – Universal with MFA” and
- “Azure Active Directory – Password”

When I try to login with SSMS I get

> Error: 18456, state 1, class 14.

When I query `[sys].[event_log]` it returns

> [event_systype]= 4, [event_subtype_desc] = login_failed_for_user.

**PROCESS FOLLOWED**

1. I have a user defined in Azure AD. (test.user@company.com)
2. In my Azure SQL database, I have set an Active Directory administrator.
3. I have created a user in SSMS test.user@company.com  with the following syntax:

   ```
    CREATE USER [test.user@company.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
   ```
4. I have assigned the user to the `db_datareader` role with the following syntax:

   ```
    ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [test.user@company.com]
   ```
5. ISSUE: When I try to connect as `test.user@company.com`, the connection fails and I get this error:

   > Login Failed for user test.user@company.com

   Details of error contains:

   > Error Number: 18456, State: 1, Class: 14

I have tried to find an answer on learn.microsoft.com, googled my ass off and found some useful resources on this, but none that actually helps me with pinpointing what to do to resolve the issue. If anybody have an Idea of what I'm doing wrong, ref *"PROCESS FOLLOWED"* I'd be forever grateful :)

[image]

Comment: Does  `GRANT CONNECT TO test.user@company.com;` work?

Comment: @JosephXu  Thanks, but no, it did not work.

Comment: @AtleRøen Did you create the user `test.user@company.com` with the AD admin account?

Comment: @LeonYue yes, I did

Comment: From the Azure CLI (could be cloud shell) ensure you can generate an access token for that account.  eg `az login` then `az account get-access-token --resource 'https://database.windows.net/'`.  If you can, then use that AccessToken with a System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, which is what SSMS will try.

Comment: @ DavidBrowne The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:
Get Token request returned http error: 400 and server response: {"error":"invalid_resource","error_description":"AADSTS500011: The resource principal named 'https://xxxxxxx.database.windows.net/' 
was not found in the tenant named xxx 
This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. 
You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.
"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=500011"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by a workaround, setting up a new database.
I did not find the cause of the problem, but it must be related to database setup "DTU"-"Basic" or some setting that I have managed to set without remembering.
Anyways, my process works when I set up a new database with "DTU"-"Standard" Configuration.

Comment: I haven't any luck with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be some kind of encoding problem. After almost giving up and using a different DB, I tried creating a new one, but **without some special characters**. And suddenly, it worked.

If you can't change your database's password, you can just edit the connection string in another editor and it works as well (Notepad, VS code, etc).